# Start JBoss Server with NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jboss

I am trying to run the JBoss server on Netbeans but the log is blocked at something like:

> [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting

The entire log is :

```
Calling "C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Finale\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
"JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values : -Xms128mx -Xmx512ms -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
___________________________
JBoss Bootstrap Environment
JBOSS_HOME: C:\jboss-7.1.1.Final
JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java
JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat - Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
__________________________
INFOS [org.jboss.modules]JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
INFO [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
INFO [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
```

I saw that the jboss repertory should be at the source (C:); I did. My environment variables must be good :

JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65

JBOSS_HOME : C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

JBOSS_CONF : default

When I added the server on Netbeans :

1- I chose the "JBoss Application Server

2- I chose the Server Location : c:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

3- The properties : Domain : standalone ; Domain Path : C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone ; Host : localhost ; Port : 8081

Can someone help me and tell me what's wrong ? 
Thanks

Comment: Which version of Netbeans?

Comment: Can you succesfully start the server from the command prompt?

Comment: @Gimby I made cd C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin and after I made a run.sh and nothing happens, but maybe I'm doing it wrong :/

Comment: Well trying run a linux shellscript on a Windows machine indeed is not going to do much.

Comment: I don't know how to do it :/ But you think that the problem can come from JBoss ? I tried with two different versions (7.1.1 and 6.1.0) but it doesn't work for both of them

Comment: Sorry, I'm detaching. This can only go anywhere with a gigantic pile of personal support, and that is not what stackoverflow is for, nor do I have the time for that.

Comment: @Gimby I just asked you if you think that the problem is JBoss, and I don't think that it's a "gigantic pile of personal support" ... Nevermind, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to start JBoss 7.1.1 with Java 8, which is not supported.

You wrote that your JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65, but the log shows that JBoss was started with jdk1.8.0_65.

> JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java

So it seems that the JAVA_HOME variable is not picked up by the start script.

Try starting JBoss with Java 7.

Comment: You're right, I tried with Java 7 and it worked ! I have an error, and I have to fix it but it looks like it works better ! Thanks :)